# Looking for the step by step breakdown for the slope of a line tangent to the curve given (x=-3, x=1.5)

Tags: calculus

$$\frac{[(x+h)^2 +4(x+h)] - [x^2+4x]}{h}$$

$$\frac{[(x^2+2hx+h^2)+(4x+4h)] - [x^2+4x]}{h}$$

This is a far as I got. I don't know how to break it down further.

Comment: Cancelling the terms without $h$'s?

Answer (score 1):

Work out the parenthesis of

$$
\frac{[(\color{red}{x^2}+2hx+h^2) + (\color{blue}{4x} + 4h)] - [\color{red}{x^2}+\color{blue}{4x}]}{h}
$$

and focus on the $\color{red}{x^2}$ and $\color{blue}{4x}$

> $$ ... = \displaystyle \frac{\color{red}{x^2} + 2hx + h^2 + \color{blue}{4x} + 4h - \color{red}{x^2} - \color{blue}{4x}}{h} = \frac{ 2hx + h^2 + 4h }{h} = 2x + 4 + h$$

Answer (score 1):

$$ \require{cancel}\frac{[( \color{green}{\cancel{x^2}}+2hx+h^2)+(\color{red}{\cancel{4x}}+4h)] - [\color{green}{\cancel{x^2}}+\color{red}{\cancel{4x}}]}{h} \equiv\frac{2\cancel{h}x+h^\cancel{2}+4\cancel{h}}{\cancel{h}}\equiv 2x+4+h. $$

Now, taking the limit $h \to 0$, we get $$\boxed{f'(x)=2x+4}.$$

If you want the slope of the tangent to the curve at $x=-3$, evaluate $f'(-3)$ (i.e. substitute $x=-3$ into $f'(x)$).

P.S. I notice that you're obtaining $f'(x)$ 'from first principles'- if this is the question, then that's great, but if the question is just to find the slope of the tangent, use the formula $$\frac{d}{dx}[x^n]=nx^{n-1}.$$

This saves a lot of time.